# How to go from wav file to spectrogram back to wav file in python?

Tags: spectrogram

Close to this question but different : [Wav To Spectrogram, Back To Wav](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41119/wav-to-spectrogram-back-to-wav?newreg=dc86095c8a9e4f86b82d841fde7f9504)

I already posted this on StackOverflow(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743968/how-to-go-from-wav-file-to-spectrogram-back-to-wav-file-in-python), but I figured this question might be more suited to be here :

Here's my problem. I have some wav files. I want to create their spectrogram. Then I want to do some stuff with the spectrogram and then I want to recreate a wav file associated to the new spectrogram. I am aware that the spectrogram doesn't have the phase information, however, since I have an original file, I can (theoretically) extract the phase from the original wav file.

I want to do that in Python (if possible), do you know a good library that would allow me to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here? How would the original phase information still mean anything sensible after you modified magnitudes?

Comment: The idea is that the modified spectrogram would represent a a "close" version of the original sound. As a result, using the original phase to recompute the sound seems a better approximation that just forgetting the phase of the original file.

Comment: Why do you want to modify the spectrogram? How is that different from regular filtering? Maybe what you want is a time-variant filter?

Comment: Spectrogram is an image, and as such a lot of deep learning techniques are very effective on spectrograms. I want to perform spectrogram reconstruction using deep learning. The end goal is still to go back to actual sound, so I need to understand how to go from an 'updated' spectrogram and an original wav file to a new wav file. The first thing I want to test there is to use the phase from the original file, but every idea is welcomed :)

Comment: yeah, but modification of a time amplitude signal inherently has phase effects, so you can't "de-intertwine" things *that* easily.

Comment: You're absolutely right. When everything is working, I'll try to adapt the phase to have an even better model. But to do that, I still need to be able to reconstruct the signal associated to a spectrogram and a phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the phase information, which isn't included in a [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram).  "Spectrogram" is just the magnitude of the STFT output.

So this is conceptually the same as [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) ↔ ISTFT, which is supported in Python now:

- [STFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html)
- [ISTFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.istft.html)

The *Examples* section in the ISTFT link does exactly what you want, modifying a STFT and inverse transforming to reduce noise.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that this week, and i'll come back to validate your answer if it works for me :)

Comment: Sorry for taking so much time to come back, I finally tried your suggestion, and it was what I needed. Thank you very much.